# Workaround for OAuth autorization

Tags: .net, oauth

Many social services use OAuth to get access to their api. But it's uncomfortably to do some stuff. For example i want to create application which store users login and password in sql server and update information about profile info in different social networks. Application is windows service not website or something. So if i know login and password can i get OAuth access token without any actions from user?

Comment: Protocols like OAuth have been developed to provide an alternative to storing user names and passwords. That being said, you can test by trying it with your own passwords and see if you can automate it?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely won't get the user's password, unless You sniff it or something else. Highly unrecommended unless You are writing malware - which I don't approve.

But if you are doing a legitimate app, then check this out:
http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/